# How to parse "1h30m" style durations into a Moment.js duration

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I would like to try and convert time duration strings to a moment.js duration object. An example of the string format is as follows: "1h30m", which should correspond to 1 hour, 30 minutes, and 0 seconds.

My first thought was to use regex so that I could pull the hours, minutes and seconds but I have a feeling that there's a more efficient way to handle it - the end goal is to use these to calculate how long until a command is run - I saw there was a library called [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) that I feel could possibly handle this, but the docs don't give a clear way on handling duration formatting in the format that I have in mind. I can provide the code I have written so far, though I don't imagine it would be of much help.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You need to parse the input to grab data and tokens, then make sense of it. A regular expression may help but isn't necessary. The strings are likely short so character–by–character parsing may be just as fast
.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use moment.js to do this - but I'm not sure if it's strictly necessary as it can also be accomplished through simple string manipulation.

**String Manipulation Approach:**

```
function parseTimeSpan(timeString) {
  let parts = timeString.split("h");
  return {
    hours: Number(parts[0]), 
    minutes: Number(parts[1].slice(0, -1))
  };
}
```

[JsFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/abzrfex9/1/)

Note this will only work with strings that contain both the hour and minute component, and does not support seconds.

**Moment.JS Approach:**

```
function parseTimeSpan(timeString) {
  return moment.duration("PT" + timeString.toUpperCase());
}
```

[JsFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hb2jq75f/)

This approach is more robust and handles far more use cases, but is slower and requires an external library.

Comment: Why post code elsewhere when you can post it as runnable snippets here?

Comment: this is what I was looking for, thanks! For clarity's sake, what exactly is "PT" doing within the momentjs code? I don't see any similar examples of it in the docs.

Comment: The "PT" is there to tell the parser that we're using an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals) formatted date. The [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/) mention that ISO8601 strings are supported. An ISO8601 duration normally looks like this: "P1Y2M10DT2H30M1S". We simply are omitting the year, month and day component, hence it becomes like this: "**PT**2H30M1S".